# Objective-C Float / Double precision

Tags: objective-c, precision, floating-point-precision

I was messing around with storing `float`s and `double`s using `NSUserDefaults` for use in an iPhone application, and I came across some inconsistencies in how the precision works with them, and how I understood it works.

This works exactly as I figured:

```
{
    NSString *key = @"OneLastKey";
    [PPrefs setFloat:235.1f forKey:key];
    GHAssertFalse([PPrefs getFloatForKey:key] == 235.1, @"");
    [PPrefs removeObjectForKey:key];
}
```

However, this one doesn't:

```
{
    NSString *key = @"SomeDoubleKey";
    [PPrefs setDouble:234.32 forKey:key];
    GHAssertEquals([PPrefs getDoubleForKey:key], 234.32, @"");
    [PPrefs removeObjectForKey:key];
}
```

This is the output GHUnit gives me:

```
'234.320007324' should be equal to '234.32'.
```

But, if I first cast the double to a `float`, and then to a `double` it works without fail:

```
{
    NSString *key = @"SomeDoubleKey";
    [PPrefs setDouble:234.32 forKey:key];
    GHAssertEquals([PPrefs getDoubleForKey:key], (double)(float)234.32, @"");
    [PPrefs removeObjectForKey:key];
}
```

I was under the assumption that numbers entered without an 'f' at the end were already considered `double`s. Is this incorrect? If so, why does casting to a `float` and then `double` work correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! Turns out my framework method `+(void)setDouble:(double)value forKey:(NSString*)key`  was actually defined as `+(void)setDouble:(`**`float`**`)value forKey:(NSString*)key`. The value passed *was* a double but was converted to a float for use in the method. A simple copy and paste issue. Too bad the Objective-C compiler didn't at least throw up a warning like it seems to do for everything else...