# Objective-C - How to increase the precision of a float number

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, precision

Can someone please show me the way to set the precision of a float number to desired length. Say I have a number 2504.6. As you see the precision here is only 1. I want to set it to six.I need this because I compare this value with the value obtained from 
 [txtInput.text floatValue]. And even if I enter 2504.6 to the text box it will add 5 more precisions and will be 2504.600098. And when I compare these two values they appear to be not equal.

Comment: Have you tried `double`?

Comment: Not I have not, would it matter? I mean, isn't double just twice bigger than float? I mean the precisions.

Comment: A `double` gives you approximately twice as much precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the numbers using `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:2504.6f];
NSDecimalNumber *input = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:txtInput.text];
NSComparisonResult result = [number compare:input];

if (result == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // number < input
} else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // number > input
} else {
    // number == input
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Floats are approximates. The way floats are stored does not allow for arbitrary precision. Floats (and doubles) are designed to store very large (or small) values, but not precise values.

If you need a very precise non-integer number, use an int (or long) and scale it. You could even write your own object class to handle that.

They won't appear to be equal

Btw this question has been asked before

[Comparing float and double data types in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024913/issue-with-float-and-double-data-types-in-objective-c/5025021#5025021)

[Objective-C Float / Double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408677/objective-c-float-double-precision)

[Make a float only show two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/how-to-set-the-float-value-to-two-decimal-number-in-objective-c)

Comment: A long only gives you about 3 decimal digits more precision than a double.

Comment: @Oli but there will be no approximation.

Comment: @Sulthan: Define "approximation".  A float **is** an integer with an associated scaling factor.

Comment: Float cannot represent all the values. A 2.4 put into a scaled long will always stay 2.4. A 2.4 put into a float is immediately converted into a 2.4000000001 or 2.3999999999

Comment: @Sulthan: A scaled long cannot represent "all the values" either.

Comment: Yes, but you have control over what it can represent

Answer (score 3):

Comparing two float variables A and B using 'equal' operator is not very good idea, cause float numbers have limited precision. The best way to compare floats is

```
fabs(A - B) < eps
```

where eps is some very small value, say 0.0001

If you're operating with strings that represent the float values you can just compare strings and not the numbers.

Comment: This only works if OP doesn't need the comparison result to be *correct* (I mean without approximations) if the user actually inputs 2504.600098.